# Cannot add a xlam as a reference. Excel 2010 throws an error "can't add a refernec to the specified file"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a bunch of Excel files that I have to convert from 2003 to 2010 format.

About five of them are written as Add-in (i.e. the isAddin attribute of the workbook is set to 'True')

Some of them has  a dependency on others. e.g. DBUtils, responsible for retrieval of data from database server, is an addin used by the other four addins. So in Excel 2003, you will see DBUtils appear as an Addin in other xls files.

As a first step of conversion, I have individually converted the xls into xlam format.

Now I am attempting to update the addin's reference such that they will point to the new xlam files instead of 2003 xls files.

It is at this point I got the "Can't add a reference to the specified file"

[image]

How can I add a reference in Excel 2010?

Answer (score 0):

an `add-in` is not a `reference` in Excel 2010.

add-ins are added using the *File* -> *Options* -> *Add-Ins*
references *tend* to be OCXs, DLLs, and such

Comment: This couldn't be more wrong...